# ReactJS: showing a list of objects from API and then filtering through them based on user search input

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is supposed to display all data fetched from API and then filter through it, according to user input (category and location of searched object). I managed to get it to search and display the searched object, but the page doesn't display all data when initialized. I know there's a mapping issue (when I map "posts" the search function works, but doesn't show anything until I search- on the other hand, when I map "allData" it shows all data but the search function doesn't work). How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categoriesSelected, setCategoriesSelected] = useState([]); 
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]); 
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); 
  const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
  const [lng, setLng] = useState("");
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL/get-categories/")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setCategories(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL/item-list/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setAllData(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, []);

  //building the categories array to show in Multiselect component
  const option = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    option.push(categories[i].name);
  }

  async function submitSearch(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response1 = await fetch(
        `URL/item-categories-list/?categories=${categoriesSelected}`
      );
      const response2 = await fetch(
        `URL/item-list-distance/?distance=${distance}&lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}`
      );
      const data1 = await response1.json();
      const data2 = await response2.json();
      console.log(data1);
      console.log(data2);
      setPosts(data1);
      setPosts(data2);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  const navigateToItem = (itemId) => {
    navigate(`/item/${itemId}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitSearch}>
          <label>
            Filter by Categories
            <Multiselect
              avoidHighlightFirstOption={true}
              isObject={false}
              options={option}
              onRemove={(event) => {
                setCategoriesSelected(event);
              }}
              onSelect={(event) => {
                setCategoriesSelected(event);
              }}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setCategoriesSelected(event);
              }}
            />
            <Location setLat={setLat} setLng={setLng} lat={lat} lng={lng} />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="range">Choose a range (kms):</label>
            <select
              id="range"
              onChange={(e) => setDistance(e.target.value)}
              value={distance}
              name="distance"
            >
              <option value={1000}>1 km</option>
              <option value={2000}>2 kms</option>
              <option value={3000}>3 kms</option>
              <option value={4000}>4 kms</option>
              <option value={5000}>5 kms</option>
              <option value={20000}>20 kms</option>
            </select>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={submitSearch}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>

      {posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Card
              display="flex"
              justifyContent="center"
              sx={{
                m: 0,
                flexGrow: 1,
                borderBottom: 1,
                borderColor: "border.main",
                borderRadius: 0,
                backgroundColor: "background.default",
              }}
            >
              <CardActionArea onClick={() => navigateToItem(post.id)}>
                <Grid container spacing={1} sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Box
                      component="img"
                      sx={{
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        border: 1,
                        borderColor: "border.main",
                        objectFit: "cover",
                        borderRadius: 0.3,
                      }}
                      alt="item"
                      src={
                        URL +
                        post.images[0].image
                      }
                    ></Box>
                  </Grid>

                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <div key={post.id}>
                      <div>
                        <strong>{post.title}</strong>
                      </div>
                      <div>{post.description}</div>
                      <div>Condition: {post.condition}</div>
                      <div>Category: {post.categories}</div>
                      <div>
                        <strong>Location</strong>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is on the "Posts" variable.you are not updating it properly.
on **submitSearch** function you are setting the **posts** variable twice
you need to merge the arrays to create the new array.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categoriesSelected, setCategoriesSelected] = useState([]); 
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]); 
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); 
  const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
  const [lng, setLng] = useState("");
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL/get-categories/")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setCategories(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL/item-list/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setAllData(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, []);

  //building the categories array to show in Multiselect component
  const option = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    option.push(categories[i].name);
  }

async function submitSearch(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  try {
    const response1 = await fetch(
      `URL/item-categories-list/?categories=${categoriesSelected}`
    );
    const response2 = await fetch(
      `URL/item-list-distance/?distance=${distance}&lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}`
    );
    const data1 = await response1.json();
    const data2 = await response2.json();
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data2);
    setPosts([...data1, ...data2]); // merge the arrays
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

  const navigateToItem = (itemId) => {
    navigate(`/item/${itemId}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitSearch}>
          <label>
            Filter by Categories
            <Multiselect
              avoidHighlightFirstOption={true}
              isObject={false}
              options={option}
              onRemove={(event) => {
                setCategoriesSelected(event);
              }}
              onSelect={(event) => {
                setCategoriesSelected(event);
              }}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setCategoriesSelected(event);
              }}
            />
            <Location setLat={setLat} setLng={setLng} lat={lat} lng={lng} />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="range">Choose a range (kms):</label>
            <select
              id="range"
              onChange={(e) => setDistance(e.target.value)}
              value={distance}
              name="distance"
            >
              <option value={1000}>1 km</option>
              <option value={2000}>2 kms</option>
              <option value={3000}>3 kms</option>
              <option value={4000}>4 kms</option>
              <option value={5000}>5 kms</option>
              <option value={20000}>20 kms</option>
            </select>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={submitSearch}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>

      {posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Card
              display="flex"
              justifyContent="center"
              sx={{
                m: 0,
                flexGrow: 1,
                borderBottom: 1,
                borderColor: "border.main",
                borderRadius: 0,
                backgroundColor: "background.default",
              }}
            >
              <CardActionArea onClick={() => navigateToItem(post.id)}>
                <Grid container spacing={1} sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Box
                      component="img"
                      sx={{
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        border: 1,
                        borderColor: "border.main",
                        objectFit: "cover",
                        borderRadius: 0.3,
                      }}
                      alt="item"
                      src={
                        URL +
                        post.images[0].image
                      }
                    ></Box>
                  </Grid>

                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <div key={post.id}>
                      <div>
                        <strong>{post.title}</strong>
                      </div>
                      <div>{post.description}</div>
                      <div>Condition: {post.condition}</div>
                      <div>Category: {post.categories}</div>
                      <div>
                        <strong>Location</strong>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It doesn't answer my question but I agree that there was an issue with setting the posts twice. I fixed it this way:  ``` const filteredPosts = data1.filter((post1) => {
        return data2.some((post2) => post1.id === post2.id);
      });
      setPosts(filteredPosts); ``` Still not sure how to display all data on the website and only filter on search.